how to make Spring security allow access to enter home page without login?
I set up spring mvs project and added spring security, i want everyone see home page without login.
here is my security configuration:
package uz.smartup.academy.bloggingplatform.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager detailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);

        detailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM user WHERE username = ?");
        detailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM role WHERE username = ?");

        return detailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authManager ->  authManager
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin", "/admin/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/posts/*", "/profile/*", "/categories/*").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/profile/*").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/css/**", "/js/**", "/photos/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(
                        form -> form.loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                                .permitAll()
                );

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}

i clear browser cage and try to add empty pattern to requestMatchers . but project still redirecting login page and compiler shows this:
2024-07-06T23:19:21.944+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-2\] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And \[Not \[RequestHeaderRequestMatcher \[expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest\]\], MediaTypeRequestMatcher \[contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@75a4ae9e, matchingMediaTypes=\[application/xhtml+xml, image/\*, text/html, text/plain\], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=\[\*/\*\]\]\]

2024-07-06T23:19:21.948+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-2\] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@76192bf1

2024-07-06T23:19:21.949+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-2\] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login

2024-07-06T23:19:21.960+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-3\] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login

2024-07-06T23:19:21.960+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-3\] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login

2024-07-06T23:19:21.977+05:00 DEBUG 4448 --- \[bloggingplatform\] \[nio-8080-exec-3\] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext



.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/home").permitAll()

it is no use, i've already tried it, plus my home page pattern is "/"

this would be because of
http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
try removing it OR setting it with customizer. The default configuration ensures that all endpoints require authentication.
